# What is my user and pass? Deploy django on AWS EC2 but can not login admin

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, web-deployment

I've followed this youtube instruction from amazon to deploy django web app to AWS EB EC2.  The website successfully ran.  But I can not login to admin.  The admin that came with django polls example. I recall that during the setup process, it prompt me for RDS setup and since my web app use MySQL, I had to pick RDS setup. When I setup the RDS, it did not prompt me to create a user, but only prompted me to create a password, which dutifully I did.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJoOnKiSYws

Similar instructions can be found on AWS, too.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html

I've tried username 'root' and password is 'blank' which works on my local pc, but of course that would make things too simple.

After that attempt failed, I did some searching in EC2 and RDS dashboard on AWS, and I found username=ebroot.

So I tried username 'ebroot' and password [rds_password_from_setup], but that didn't work.

I've tried many other combinations of usernames and passwords but nothing works.  This might be a stupid question to ask the online community, but what do you suppose is my username and password that RDS might accept?

Comment: by "Admin" do you mean the django admin? (I don't want to watch the whole video)

Comment: yes,  it's the django admin.  let me revise the question to clarify. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to create an admin user for my Django app on Beanstalk I created a custom Django command that I invoke in **containers_commands**, so there is no need for human input at all! Moreover I defined the user/password as environment variables so I can put my code under version control safely. The implementation of my command is something similar to this:

```
import os

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from com.cygora.apps.users.models.User import User

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        username = os.environ['SUPER_USER_NAME']
        if not User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            User.objects.create_superuser(username,
                                          os.environ['SUPER_USER_EMAIL'],
                                          os.environ['SUPER_USER_PASSWORD'])
```

then in my beanstalk config:

```
container_commands:
  02_create_superuser_for_django_admin:
    command: "python manage.py create_cygora_superuser"
    leader_only: true
```

ps: if you never created a custom Django commands before, all you have to to is to create a package: `management.commands` in your desired app (ie: /your_project/your_app/management/commands/the_command.py), Django will load it automatically (and you can see it when typing `python manage.py --help`)

Comment: Dave, you rock! Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome ...btw if you want to follow my blog http://www.daveoncode.com I'm gonna publish some new stuff on the argument ;)

Comment: What is com.cygora.apps.users.models.User ?

Comment: It was the custom user model of my application